# How can I get text field to have a random variable everytime I refresh the page, with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have a variable x which have its value between 20 to 100. (only multiples of 10)
  x = (((Math.floor(Math.random()* 9)) + 2 ) * 10 );

How can I put this variable x's value directly into HTML input text field with the help of JavaScript, such that every time I refresh the page, it gets changed randomly.

```
var input = document.getElementById('win-score').value;
var x;

x = (((Math.floor(Math.random()* 9)) + 2 ) * 10 );
input = x;


// Undefined, 0, null or "" are COERCED to false
// Anything else is COERCED to true

/*        if(input) {
                win = input;
          } else {
                win = 100;
          } */
}; 

document.querySelector('.win-button').addEventListener('click', function() {

    document.getElementById('win-score').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('win-score').value = input;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

See below code, instead of assigning value to variable assign it to element

```js
var input = document.getElementById('win-score').value ; 
var x;
 x = (((Math.floor(Math.random()* 9)) + 2 ) * 10 );
document.getElementById('win-score').value = x;
document.querySelector('.win-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
document.getElementById('win-score').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('win-score').value = input;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="win-score">
<button type="button" class="win-button">Click</button>
```

What you were doing is, you assign "x" value to "input" variable.
either you can directly assign value to element or assign "input" variable value back to element just after 
"`input = x`"

Comment: But input itself is a variable. It's not the same input tag of HTML. It's created in javascript. right ?

Comment: yes exactly, input just hold value for you, so that you can use it in anywhere in java-script but limited to its scope.

Comment: okay.. so i have to declare input in the global scope too ?? if i am right

Comment: No, you don't have to declare input with global scope. See your html and javascript is totally different, you have to make sure thar whatever change you doing on you variable should get assigned to html so that it get visible on UI as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

on page load write below code.

```
var x = (((Math.floor(Math.random()* 9)) + 2 ) * 10 ); // get random number
document.getElementById('win-score').value = x;  // set value to input
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Djordje Vujicic said you can set the value using

```
    document.getElementById('win-score').value = x;
```

just set this value as follows:

```
    window.onload="myFunction()";

    function myFunction(){
     var x = (((Math.floor(Math.random()* 9)) + 2 ) * 10 );
     document.getElementById('win-score').value = x;
    }
```

Comment: what is the purpose of using window.onload(). I just removed document.getElementById('win-score').value = x;        from that function and put it in initializing function. Made (x) a global variable and it worked. It is a simple way, but is it correct? Or i should go with window.onload. I don't know about it much but i guess it got to be about window object and about refreshing the page.

Comment: You can do either ways. But window.onload calls the function every time your page loads which is suitable for your requirement. window.onload ensures that your function is called every time your page is refreshed.

Comment: Okay, But right now it's still working fine even after refreshing. But i will keep in mind this method to use in the future, as i think it's more appropriate. Thanks